Do Primeval team ever use cyanide-tipped bullets?
Do the Primeval team ever use cyanide-tipped bullets against the various monsters?
As I understand it the cyanides are lethal to all oxygen-breathing life forms, which would include most of the prehistoric monsters. The only exception I recall are the Pre-Cambrian worms, which couldn't survive long in our time anyway. So these would seem the ideal weapon.

I see no indication that such bullets were ever used in the show. In general, poisoned bullets are rare as a form of self-defense because poison takes time to act, and death via bullet holes is more likely to hit first as per the mention on the TV Tropes entry for Poisoned Weapons.

Generally speaking, poisoned weapons were not very commonly used in warfare, as they were an unreliable and overly complicated way of killing a person. Any injury inflicted with a poisoned weapon is more than likely to bleed out faster than the poison could be absorbed; even if were to be absorbed in sufficient amounts, it would take some time before the effects actually come into play. Typically, poisoned weapons were mainly used for hunting, in which case the poison can be given enough time to take hold and debilitate an animal so that a hunter can catch up and deliver the final blow. For obvious reasons, this requires a poison that is relatively benign and/or destroyed by the heat of cooking. For example, Curare, mentioned below, can't be absorbed through the digestive system - it needs to hit the bloodstream directly through a wound to have an effect.

